# Python Recording points on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Still new to python, so I a little help would be appreciated.

I have two series of data like shown in the image below, one with x axis of age and one is depth, and different y axis too. Which have troughs and peaks that look offset to each other. Which is true but, that offset changes throughout time. My aim is to calibrate these two graphs on a common timescale by manually taking the coordinates of the peaks which match. And then working out dx1/dx2 over a selected range, i.e between the first two clicks and then the same between the next two set of manually selected clicks. And from that I can transpose to the same graph both as an age.

My issue through, is how to seperate the clicking and recording points on the figure as two separate datasets. I think the best way is to have two figures on top of each other, but I don't know how to edit the function so.

Many thanks in advance

[Image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05qch.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import trapz
import sys

date_record="Date.csv"  #The record that you have a timescale for and a value
depth_record="Depth.csv"
date_record=pd.read_csv(date_record)
depth_record=pd.read_csv(depth_record)

date=date_record[[0]]
print(date)
del_18O=date_record[[1]]

depth=depth_record[[0]]
Corg=depth_record[[1]]

x=date
y=del_18O

x1=depth
y1=Corg

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

ax2 = ax.twinx().twiny()
ax2.plot(x1,y1,color="green")

ax = plt.gca()  
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])

ax2 = plt.gca()  
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])

coords = []

def onclick(event):
    global ix, iy
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print ('x =',ix , 'y =',iy)

    global coords
    coords.append((ix, iy))
    ax2.plot(ix,iy,color="red",markersize=5,marker=".",linestyle="")


    if len(coords) == 5:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        #print(coords)
        #ax2.plot(coords,color="red",markersize=5,marker=".",linestyle="")
        #print(coords)
        sys.exit


    return coords
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
print("adding")
print(coords)
```

Comment: Your question is pretty broad or unclear. Most importantly: this code looks as if clicking registered data points based on the coordinates, without using the underlying data sets at all. Is it not thus? I'd expect the code to check the data points present in the plot, and find "close" ones. Then it's almost natural to extend that to search for two data sets (you need to watch if points overlap, though).

Comment: @AndrasDeak

Sorry, it is hard to explain a question in words. The code, can't check to see if close ones match automatically because the scales are different. But it is possible to see by eye, that there is a huge drop in both followed by two small peaks for example. The aim is to then click on the peak for the one dataset and a separate click for the other corresponding peak. So ultimately i have manually highlighted the matching coordinates between graphs.